# How do I check the access to every node?

Tags: 8

I need a quick solution to restrict access to nodes based on the contents of field. I've built the skeleton of a module and managed to restrict access to a custom route.
Now, the service that redirects to access check is this:

```
services:
  access_check.untitled_check:
    class: Drupal\untitled\Access\UntitledAccessCheck
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _access_untitled_check }
```

This only applies to routes with _access_untitled_check in the requirements array.

How can I have **all nodes**  checked?
Can I add _access_untitled_check to nodes' requirements array?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do *alter* or *hook* into node access. You can find out more by reading the [Node Access Rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/8) page on api.drupal.org.

Briefly node access works like this (paraphrasing from the aforementioned documentation page):

1. Users with 'bypass node access' are granted access.
2. Invoke implementations of hook_node_access
3. Invoke implementations of hook_node_grants

Finally,

> To see how to write a node access module of your own, see node_access_example.module.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found. No routes, no services, no controllers. Only `hook_node_access` as advised by @mradcliffe

```
function modulename_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {
  $bundle = $node->bundle();
  $user = $account->id();
  $refs = $node->field_with_references->referencedEntities();

  $condition = ... 

  return AccessResult::forbiddenIf( $condition );
}
```